# Broadcast traffic on large vlan in numbers

Tags: networking, vlan, subnet

I'm looking for the magic number of how many clients make sense to have on a single VLAN, before the broadcast traffic becomes a real issue.

Preferably, I'd also like to know what a good number of clients in the same VLAN on switches at the market today - E.G Cisco Catalyst 3750 are able to handle in terms of broadcast traffic before it starts to significantly affect network performance overall.

Comment: I'm trying to determine how to calculate "too many hosts on the same LAN segment" :)

Comment: Trying to calculate how many hosts per VLAN by looking at broadcast traffic amounts is not the right approach.  Real app traffic and load is a better start.  If you EVER get to a point on a 3750 where broadcast traffic affects network performance you haven't configured the switch's storm control, etc. correctly.

Comment: @JonSkarpeteig this is easy - evaluate the RMON stats at a port with a noteworthy amount of traffic over some time and see if the broadcast frame numbers represent a significant percentage of the total traffic. If they do, then you have "too many".

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic number like you're looking for, because the answer depends on too many environment-specific factors.  Cisco's recommendation from the 90's was no larger than a /24 (256 clients), and that's still a decent rule of thumb, though you can usually get away with a /23 or /22 these days, provided you don't have a lot of traffic relying on broadcasts or older client devices that might not be able to handle a lot of network traffic.

Comment: But how much traffic in numbers are we talking about?

Comment: @JonSkarpeteig Depends.  That's like asking "how fast can I drive my car on the highway?"  Even knowing the specifics on the car, we can't answer that, because the limiting factor isn't the car, it's the conditions on the road and/or the driver.  Likewise, in this scenario, the limiting factor isn't going to be your switch, but your clients and what services they run.

Comment: I'm looking for concrete examples. Having a specific car, running on a specific highway should yield a specific speed :-)

Comment: @JonSkarpeteig No, it shouldn't, and doesn't.  One hour, going 65 may be fine, and the next hour, during rush hour traffic, going 65 will kill you, because you'll slam into the stopped car in front of you.  Same problem here.  It depends, and the actual limiting factors in your question you haven't given details on.

Answer (score 1):

Managed switches often come with a feature called "broadcast storm control" which kicks in after a certain threshold of broadcast traffic is reached. By default, this threshold [often is at 20% of the link's capacity](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/software/release/12.1_22ea/SCG/swtrafc.html#wp1229877) which is already considered "excessive".

The major trouble will not be with the switches since those should be able to handle the frame forwarding at full link speed no matter if it is broadcast or unicast. The problem is likely to arise with your hosts and devices as each broadcast frame is forwarded for handling by the network stack and thus consumes CPU resources on each and every host receiving it. Which would not cause a lot of trouble for the PCs connected to the network, but may knock out appliances and management interfaces (IPMI, print servers, switch or router management, ...)

That being said, you likely would need a *lot* of hosts to even reach 10% peak in broadcasts in a properly configured Gigabit Ethernet network with "common" Windows hosts. Assuming 1 broadcast frame of 1500 bytes per host per second (which would be a lot already), you would need more than 8000 hosts to saturate 10% of the Gigabit link's bandwidth.

I also would recommend reading [this article by Rob VandenBrink](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Layer+2+Network+Protections+%96+reloaded!/7708) at the ISC diary.